# can't save new data, and Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, laravel-5, sum, laravel-query-builder

[image]

### Model in laravel

> "Array to string conversion (SQL: update `spent_times` set `updated_at` = 2018-10-18 06:02:29, `spent_time` = 12, `percentage` = 60.00, `task_category` = testing where `id` = 7) ◀"

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today()->toDateString();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage]);


        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category', $task_category)->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time, $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = SpentTime::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller in laravel

in function store, can't save data and can't calculation data by category when create new data, data should be calculated and entered into the table as pict. 
[image]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason')
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```

Comment: you creating  $new_raspent_time->task_category as an arry and using it as a string

Comment: @ImranQamer So what should I use? :) ask for help

Comment: can you show me your table data?

Comment: Also post complete error message with line number and complete query in error.

Comment: @ImranQamer in table spent_times : id, spent_time, daily_spent_time, percentage, daily_percentage, task_category, reason, and plan_id
table plans : id, assign, estimated_time, user_story, lateness, index, and project_id

Comment: @ImranQamer 
`Array to string conversion (SQL: update `spent_times` set `updated_at` = 2018-10-18 06:40:11, `spent_time` = 12, `percentage` = 60.00, `task_category` = testing where `id` = 7)'

it's an error when I create new data with a new category, when I leave an error like that.

Comment: ok, you must combine where clauses seperately

Comment: like where('task_category', 'testing')->where('daily_spent_time', '12')

Comment: @ImranQamer Yes, the results of the calculation are correct, just can't save and the error remains as above

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on below line

```
$new_spent_time->percentage = SpentTime::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
```

Here you assigning `$spent_time->task_category` (an array) to `'task_category'` (a string field).

Change value of above variable it will fix your issue.

Comment: `$new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category', $spent_time->task_category)->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);'
like this?

Comment: don't use where? just use the sum?

Comment: but, if i don't use where, then all categories read everything, not the same category

Comment: sorry can't, is there a solution for converting arrays to strings? oh yeah, why don't you use a teamviewer?

Comment: is there a solution for converting arrays to strings?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand the purpose of the mistake, can you help me please?

Comment: you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889490/how-to-calculate-data-by-category-when-creating-new-data-with-the-same-category/52890721#52890721

Answer (score 0):

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today()->toDateString();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{

        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);


        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $request['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$spent_time->task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $request['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason')
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```