# how to calculate data by category when creating new data with the same category

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```

### View

[image]

> with problems, when saving create new data then an error "Trying to get property of non-object"

[image]

> but there is one data that can save when creating new data, but cannot yet calculate the data, and while the other categories cannot be like that, instead the error

[image]

> what should be corrected from this problem?

Comment: `$new_spent_time` is not being saved at all. You also are creating updating both `properties` and array `keys`. Choose one.

Comment: So what should be improved? sorry I'm still learning, so still don't understand your point.

Comment: The structure is a bit difficult to understand, I took a look but got confused where you used the `where()` clauses. You can run `where()`  on one record.

Comment: so what to change?

Comment: Could you update your question with your model and model relations so I understand what is trying to be achieved.

Comment: Isn't this line `$task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;` the problem in the question? I suppose the returned value of the `$new_spent_time` is null or something _non object_. I think you may need to check `if($new_spent_time !== null)` or other checks... how about that?

Comment: @thisiskelvin when creating new data with the same category, the spent_time data should calculate with the previous data (the same category), which is in the TST table, as well as the percentage

Comment: @Qiuwatobi $new_spent_time there is data

Comment: I would argue that you don't need to add this to a database record. This can be calculated using another model function. The reason being is that each record at some point will not have the same time spent as it hasn't been saved. Using a scope will be able to calculate the `time and `percentages` when required. I'll create an example to explain further.

Comment: @thisiskelvin thank's, I'm waiting for the answer

Comment: Is it like this?
`public function getDailySpentTimeAttribute()
    {
        return self::where('task_category', $this->task_category['daily_Spent_time'] == 'daily_spent_time')
            ->get()
            ->sum('daily_spent_time');
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update Answer

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    $task_category = $spent_time->task_category;

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{

        $spent_time['spent_time'] = $spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $spent_time['percentage'] = $spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $spent_times = SpentTime::orderBy('task_category')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->paginate(10);
    $user_stories = Plan::pluck('user_story', 'id');
    $real = new SpentTime;

    return view('reals.index', compact('spent_times', 'user_stories', 'real'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{    
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason'),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `SpentTime` model, you are able to create [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) which are functions that can be used here to query the sum a day of all relating records:

```
public function getDailySpentTimeAttribute()
{
    return self::where('task_category_id', $this->task_category_id)
        ->get()
        ->sum('daily_spent_time');
}

public function getDailyPercentageAttribute()
{
    return self::where('task_category_id', $this->task_category_id)
        ->get()
        ->sum('daily_percentage');
}
```

Here, we create two `accessors`, one to get the daily spent time and another to get the daily percentage, for all records based on relating `task_category`.

There can be called using the following:

```
$dailySpentTime = SpentTime::find($id)->dailySpentTime;

// or within your blade template

{{ $spentTime->dailySpentTime }}
```

## Update

Within your controller, as you no longer have to run any calculations upon saving, you can do the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'task_category' => $request->get('task_category'),
        'reason'        => $request->get('reason'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact('spent_time'));
}
```

Make sure to delete your custom `findOrCreate()` method which is currently overriding the laravel version.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: is there an additional call to the controller?

Comment: Only a normal save is needed within the `store()` controller method. `dailySpentTime` can be called on any `SpentTime` record.

Comment: Updated. Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: error `Call to a member function getDailySpentTimeAttribute() on boolean`

Comment: Can you `dd()` `$spent_time` to see what is echoed out.

Comment: What data can you see?

Comment: Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json You need to `append` the new values to the json response.

Comment: Is it like this?

Comment: No. And you are returning server times in the functions. Take some time to learn about accessors and other functionality for laravel. It will definitely help in the future.

Comment: can create new data if make it, but can't calculated data by same category 
`public function getDailySpentTimeAttribute($value)
    {  
        return $this->attributes['daily_spent_time'] = ucfirst($value);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

### update Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{

        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the data is there, when dd($spent_time);

```
dd($spent_time);
```

[image]