# can't save calcution data when create new data

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{

        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;

        $new_spent_time->task_category = (['{task_category}' => $task_category, 
                                        '{daily_spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time,
                                        '{daily_percentage}' => $new_spent_time->daily_percentage,
                                        '{spent_time}' => $new_spent_time->spent_time,
                                        '{percentage}' => $new_spent_time->percentage, $new_spent_time->task_category]);

        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = (int)$new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = (int)$new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

> when creating new databases with the same category, and save cannot calculate data

[image]

> error like this, and can't save calcution data when create new data

[image]

Comment: `task_category` is supposed to be a `JSON` field or what? What you want to store there?

Comment: @azeós I want to save daily_spent_time data, daily_percentage data and display it to spent_time or table (ST) as well as percentage to (T% Done) which has the same category, so the point is that the data cannot be saved and cannot calculate, is there something wrong with this source code?

Comment: Show us the table structure. Forget about the code, write an example of the exact `string` you want to store in `$new_spent_time->task_category`. Probably you need to surround it with double quotes.

Comment: in table spent_times : id, spent_time, daily_spent_time, task_category, reason, and plan_id
table plans : id, assign, estimated_time, user_story, lateness, index, and project_id

Comment: Show us an example of the string you want to store in `task_category`.

Comment: example testing

Comment: or you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868027/cant-save-new-data-and-array-to-string-conversion/52868155?noredirect=1#comment92695681_52868155